# "Imported" a JSON-"list" into R, how do I make a proper, Excel-like table out of it?

Tags: r, json

Edit: With the follwoing code I could make a table as desired:

```
library(jsonlite)
data3<-fromJSON("https://www.ser-ag.com/sheldon/management_transactions/v1/overview.json?pageSize=10000&pageNumber=0&sortAttribute=byDate&fromDate=20181201&toDate=20211131")
names(data3)
View(data3$itemList)
```

I need to take the following [JSON file](https://www.ser-ag.com/sheldon/management_transactions/v1/overview.json?pageSize=10000&pageNumber=0&sortAttribute=byDate&fromDate=20181201&toDate=20221131) (is this even a JSON file?) and turn it into a nice table, like you would do in Excel, using R.

I already "imported" the file into R, using this code (there you also have the link to the "JSON-file"):

```
 library(rjson)
url<-"[https://www.ser-ag.com/sheldon/management_transactions/v1/overview.json?pageSize=10000&pageNumber=0&sortAttribute=byDate&fromDate=20181201&toDate=20221131][1]"
document<-fromJSON(file = url, method = "C")
```

What do I need to do so that I get a nice table? with View(document) I get more of a list than a table. In my table, the entries under name (like buysellindicator) should be a column name and the corresponding entries in value should then form the rows. Please see the attached pictures.

[image: This is what I see when I enter View(document)]

[image: Here is a second screenshot]

Comment: `url` looks wrong; I don't think it should have the square brackets or the `[1]` at the end. Use `fromJSON()` in the `jsonlite` package and you should find that `document$itemList` is a dataframe.

Comment: @neilfws I think the site added the brackets itself, it is not in my original R script.

I will try this out, thank you

Comment: Thanks to @neilfws, I could solve my problem. I edited the original post and inserted the used code that worked for me.